# Exponential execution time for CREATE INDEX

Tags: sqlite

We are working on a project that does millions of inserts in to a sqlite3 database and have run in to a performance issue that is inconsistent across different machines when calling:

```
CREATE INDEX blocking_map_key_idx ON blocking_map (key)
```

A CentOS 5.8 performs this CREATE INDEX in less than 1 hour
A Mac OSX Mountain Lion doesn't complete after more than 6 hours.

They have the same PRAGMA settings, same Sqlite version (3.3.6), and both seem to be using a similar memory footprint.

Is there a significant way sqlite performs on these two operating systems? If not, is it possibly a disk or memory issue?

The full code we are running can be [found here](https://github.com/open-city/dedupe/blob/sqlite_optimization/examples/sqlite_example/sqlite_example.py) and is part of a larger [open source deduplication library](https://github.com/open-city/dedupe).

Comment: Of course it's a disk issue. What kind if storage is used for temporary files?

Comment: I tried both file and memory (using [PRAGMA temp_store](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_temp_store)) with no measurable effect.

The more I think about it, the more I think it must be a memory issue.  The CentOS machine has 50Gb+ of memory where my mac has 8Gb. However, my OS is not using more than 1.6Gb (with plenty to spare) for this process. Is the OS just outsmarting me?

Comment: Check Db settings for max memory it can use before dumping to disc. It may be calculated as % of memory available / present at install time.

Comment: Just one minor comment: 6 hrs vs 1 hr is not exponential.  I also agree it might be memory related. sqlite is very good at grabbing as much memory as it can.